# returning a string containing href="@Url.Action in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, string, razor

```
function iconFormatter(value, row, index) {
    var idNode = row.nodeId;
    if (row.isFile === true) {
        return '<img src="../Test/file.png" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><a class="file-download" href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Casename", new { fileId = "' + row.nodeId + '" })"> ' + value + '</a>'
    }
    return value
}
```

In `fileId = "' + row.nodeId + '"`, row.nodeId is returning the hex string value instead of int value.

Can someone please suggest the required correction here?

Comment: `@Url.Action` will be interpreted on the server-side before the page is rendered. `row` is a client-side Javascript variable which is instantiated after the page has been rendered. The two cannot directly interact in the manner you're attempting here. I would suggest you research the difference between the server side and client side logic, as this is a fundamental concept of web development. With regard to your question, you could potentially manually append `fileid=${row.nodeId}` to the string output by `@Url.Action` - but this would depend on your specific use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing server-side and client-side code.  The two execute at entirely different times in entirely different contexts (often on entirely different computers).

Instead, use the server-side code to generate the URL with a known placeholder, then you can replace that placeholder in the client-side code.  For example:

```
function iconFormatter(value, row, index) {
  // generate the URL from server-side code
  // (hint: view the page source in the browser and see what this becomes)
  let url = '@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Casename", new { fileId = "PLACEHOLDER" })';

  if (row.isFile === true) {
    // replace the placeholder
    url = url.replace('PLACEHOLDER', encodeURIComponent(row.nodeId));

    // use the resulting URL
    return '<img src="../Test/file.png" style="margin-left: 10px;" /><a class="file-download" href="' + url + '"> ' + value + '</a>'
  }
  return value
}
```

(If one were to look only at the client-side code this result might look unnecessary.  That's because *to the client-side code* these are all string literals.  The client-side code is unaware of the server-side functionality of `@Url.Action`.)